# Don't show partialView inside a div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi everyone I have use a <%= Ajax.ActionLink like this...

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Change Image", "ChangeImgWithData", "Package", 
                 new AjaxOptions() {UpdateTargetId="img", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace , HttpMethod="GET"})%>

<div id="img">  </div>
```

in my controller I have this..

```
  public ActionResult ChangeImgWithData()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("~/Views/Package/_Change.ascx");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
```

my Request.IsAjaxRequest() is null, I dont no why?? I want to show partialView _change inside the img div

any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: IsAjaxRequest returns a bool, a value type, which cannot be null... What is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why IsAjaxRequest() is null but you could create an action that returns the partial. Something like this

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Change Image", "ChangeImgWithDataAjax", "Package", 
                 new AjaxOptions() {UpdateTargetId="img", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace , HttpMethod="GET"})%>

<div id="img">  </div>


public ActionResult ChangeImgWithData()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult ChangeImgWithDataAjax()
{
  return PartialView("~/Views/Package/_Change.ascx");  
}
```

You might also have to reference the jquery unobtrusive-ajax library in the view.

```
 <script src="<% Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I create my action and return a partial (I put the code) but don't show nothing in the div.

Comment: Are you referencing the ASP.NET Ajax script libraries?